# Does Shri Vaishnava sannyasa rules restrict their monks to enter into Shiva temples?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, shiva, sri-vaishnava, sannyasa

I read in a book on Kinkar Madhav Ramanuj Jeor that ShrinVaishnava saints are NOT permitted by the sect to enter into Shiva Temples.

We know that both Shiva and Vishnu say in different scriptures that they are One and one who discriminates between the two will be fallen.

What is the scriptural basis of such a rule for the Shri Vaishnava monks then?

Or is the book providing wrong information?

Comment: It would also be interesting to know if Shaivaite saints enter Vishnu temples.

Comment: Their "Narayana" is not the Vaishnavite Narayana. @Partha Please see https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/why-are-narayana-and-vishnu-merged-as-tags

Comment: My guess would be that the number of practicing Hindus who have for Vishnu the same antipathy Vaishnavites even today have for Siva (although it is lessening) is negligible @Partha

Comment: There are two divisions in the Sri Vaishnava sect: Vadakalais and Thenkalais. Vadakalais undergo a ritual called Bharanyasam where they take an oath not to worship any gods other than Vishnu. Generally Sri Vaishnavas avoid worshipping Anya Devatas.  Also, Sri Vaishnavas don't accept equality between Shiva and Vishnu. Shiva to them is a Jiva as opposed to Narayana who is Ishwara.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury, also the common complaint that sri vaishnavites 'hate' shiva is misplaced, because they don't hate shiva the deity, they hate the concept that any deity is equal to Vishnu. There is a big difference between a 'shiva'-dveshi , and a 'shiva=vishnu'-dveshi.

Comment: @ram I agree but people actually fail to see this. I **personally accept Vishnu=Shiva** but I will strongly disagree if somebody equals people who believe in **Hari-Hara-bheda** with "Shiva-dveshis".